# What does the command tf vc scorch do?

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

In the build logs of TFS builds I have seen the use of the command `tf vc scorch`. This looks rather interesting and seems to be something like `git clean` and could be quite helpful but for some strange reason `scorch` is not documented. Is this some internal thing that is not intended for public use?

Typing `tf vc /?` does not list the `scorch` command and `tf vs scorch /?` does not explain the parameters. It is also [not listed on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands).

Where can I find its full documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding a "/?" to the command line will give you a description of the command and its parameters

```
tf.exe vc scorch /?
```

Result is:

> Microsoft (R) TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version 15.117.26830.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Ensures that your local disk is identical to the server's view of the
>   working copy.
>
> tf vc scorch [/diff] [/noprompt] [/preview] [/recursive] [/ignore] [/unmapped]
>                [/exclude:itemspec1,itemspec2,...] [itemspec]

Addition 23/10: with the help of the [link](https://wiert.me/2012/09/20/tfpt-treeclean-exclude-suo-user-is-what-i-use-most-and-recommend-does-any-tool-exist-to-help-sync-a-directory-with-tfs-stack-overflow/) supplied by Andy-MSFT clarifies that adding */diff* will force the algorithm to diff files that are still read-only to make sure that they are in fact unchanged from the workspace version.

Comment: Most of the paramters seem kind of obvioud. Any idea what `/diff` does?

Comment: It should similar as `tfpt scorch /diff` mentioned here: https://wiert.me/2012/09/20/tfpt-treeclean-exclude-suo-user-is-what-i-use-most-and-recommend-does-any-tool-exist-to-help-sync-a-directory-with-tfs-stack-overflow/

Comment: I have added answer for the extended question above.