# What does the argument `vc` add to the command `tf`?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

Running `tf scorch` behaves as I'd expect.  However, running `tf scorch /?` says the syntax for this command should be `tf vc scorch`.  Looking elsewhere on SO I've found this latter syntax used: [What does the command tf vc scorch do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785939/what-does-the-command-tf-vc-scorch-do).

Does the `vc` argument have any impact / is there any good reason to include or exclude it?

Comment: It would appear to be an disambiguator command, for when a `tf vc foo` and `tf git foo` collide.

Comment: Perfect; thanks @CodeCaster

Comment: @CodeCaster You can post your comment as the answer, then JohnLBevan can accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @Andy yeah I know how answers work, but it was a guess. If you can confirm it to be correct, preferably with a source, I'd be happy to post it as an answer.

Comment: FYI: Added comment on the official doc site asking that documentation for `VC` be added: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands.  Hopefully we can update this question with an official answer once that appears.  Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `tf.exe /?` and it will tell you:

```
Microsoft (R) TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version 15.127.27130.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Type tf vc help for a list of supported Version Control commands.
Type tf git help for a list of supported Git commands.
Type tf settings help for a list of supported server settings commands.
```

So there are a number of TFVC commands, a number of Git commands and a couple of settings commands. Each of these categories already share the `help`, `permission` and `view` command, these require disambiguation.

By including `vc` or `git` you're explicitly telling the command line which subcommand you want to use. For backwards compatibility, some commands are automatically routed to `vc` without specifying the top level differentiator.

Comment: One note: older versions of TF do not recognise the `VC` parameter.  I'm not sure which version this was introduced in; certainly 2010 SP1 does not recognise it, 2013 SP1 does.