# Team foundation client command to reset workspace

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, tfs-power-tools, tf-cli

Is there a command (or series of commands) to sync a TFVC workspace with the server, ensuring that what's on disk exactly matches what's checked in to the server.

`tf vc scorch` almost does what's needed, in that it syncs the client workspace with the server's version of that workspace, but if a new item's been created on the client and added to source control, though not yet checked in, that item remains after scorch is run.  NB: I'm using the TF Client version of scorch rather than the power tools version, as I'm working with VS2017 (`scorch` is supported from VS2013 SP1), should that make any difference.

Related, I'm aware that power tools includes a `treeclean` command; however that only impacts items not under source control; not those added to version control but not checked in.  https://adamprescott.net/2011/09/12/clean-tfs-workspaces-with-scorch-treeclean/.

The only way I can think of to achieve this is to delete (`tf vc workspace /delete /collection:"https://$MyInstance.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection" $MyWorkspace`) & recreate (`tf workspace /new $MyWorkspace /collection:"https://$MyInstance.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"`) the workspace, before running a recursive get to repopulate the new folder.  However, that feels like the long-way-round for something which I'd assume would be simple...

We're using `TFVC` rather than `Git` because we're working with `Dynamics AX`, which does not natively support `Git`.

The reason I want to delete such objects is because this script will run on a build server, where I want to ensure we build exactly what's checked in to source control.  Whilst in theory no one should be creating new objects on the build server, I don't like to rely on that assumption / want to make this script as robust as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd missed the [undo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/tfvc/undo-command) command: `TF.exe vc undo * /recursive /noprompt`.

Running this command before running [get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-command) and then [scorch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786149/361842) ensures that my workspace exactly matches the latest server version.

Here's the complete code used to sync the current workspace with the server.  NB: This command assumes that `tf.exe`'s directory is included in the `path` environment variable (or you can replace `tf` with `"...\path\to\tf.exe"`), that the current/working directory is mapped in source control, and that your tf credentials are cached (otherwise include the `/login` argument with username and password).  I've not included `/all`, '/overwrite', or '/force' on the `get` command, since `scorch` will cover this anyway; the main purpose of the `get` here is to ensure our workspace is "pointing at" the latest definition.

```
tf vc undo * /recursive /noprompt
tf vc get * /recursive /noprompt
tf vc scorch * /recursive /noprompt /diff
```

NB: The [vc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47910136/361842) above is superfluous / just ensures that were there a possibility for ambiguity the system would know to use `tfvc`'s version of the command instead of the `git` version.