# Way to remove the files/Directories from Excluded Changes in TFVC for Visual Studio Code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to remove the files/Directories from Excluded Changes in TFVC for Visual Studio Code. I have configured Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio Code and it takes too much time to load because each and every time it check the changes of all the files in folders **node_modules** ,**dist**. I found it detect more than 4K files. I have to remove these directories.

Comment: From the command line, you can use the [`tf.exe scorch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786149/21567) command. Having that said, you do realize that you may still "need" this files to build/run your application, do you? So deleting them may only be a temporary relief.

Comment: Maybe [Richard Banks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source#21102343) can help you?

Comment: Hi @Christian.K. Thanks for your reply. You are right I don't want to delete I just have to remove it from the TFS  pending check in list. From Visual Studio I have also added the  ".tfignore" file its working fine with Visual Studio but for Visual Studio Code its not working.

Comment: Hi @HaaLeo , I have already applied that added  ".tfignore" file and added the directory which I didn't want to commit its working well in visual studio but not working for visual studio code extension TFSVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add [files.exclude](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) in workspace settings:

1. Go to File > Preferences > Settings
2. Add `files.exclude` to the `settings.json`

For example:

```
 "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
  },
```

You could refer to cases below:

[How do I hide certain files from the sidebar in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140112/how-do-i-hide-certain-files-from-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code)

[How can I exclude a directory from Visual Studio Code "Explore" tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258543/how-can-i-exclude-a-directory-from-visual-studio-code-explore-tab/33277809)